# Multi-threading in Python using map(fn, iterable) never calling function

Tags: python, multithreading, generator

I have a generator which I use to gather 50 items to process at a time:

```
batch_generator = retrieve_batch()
```

I've then used the `map` function provided in the `multiprocessing.dummy` module to call a function for each item in my iterable (generator) however I can see that the function supplied to `map` is never called despite the generator executing and, I'm assuming, returning a result.

Just to note that I'm happy that the generator is working as it works on a single thread.

Can anyone tell me if this is an approach which should work as I'm fairly new to python and am approaching these problems for the first time.

Useful code:

```
def something():
    batch_generator = retrieve_batch()
    pool.map(_run_process_on_batch, batch_generator)

def _run_process_on_batch(batch):
    print 'I here'
```

Comment: `batch_generator = retrieve_batch()` What *exactly* does this return?

Comment: Hi @TomDalton, the method returns a dict of "Persons" by their id. This works in a single thread so I think it must have something to do with the approach I'm using.

Comment: It might be that `pool.map` will pass the item to the function, but your function doesn't take any parameters, each function call in pool.map fails silently. Try changing using `def _run_process_on_batch(person_id):`

Comment: Also, as a separate point, a *generator* is a specific construct in python, which is very different from a dictionary, so try to avoid using it as part of a variable name unless the variable really does contain a generator!

Comment: @TomDalton The retrieve_batch method yields a map, does this not make it a generator? I've also had to amend the question as the code was incomplete (rushed it on the way out the door last night). The _run_process_on_batch did have a single argument (batch) which I had expected to be a map

Comment: Can you make your sample code complete? i.e Show us how you are invoking something() and creation of  the pool.

Comment: As above, can you show the code for `retrieve_batch`? Not really sure what you mean by "yields a map" - e.g. it's a generator that yields a single dict? It's a generator that yields many dicts? It yields a map function? etc